# Azure SQL database row limit and table refresh

Tags: azure-sql-database, grafana, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

Currently I'm visualizing data in Grafana from Azure IotHub to Stream analytics to a SQL database.
I'm able to read and visualize the data but it is showing the affected row's last data. Later the new data is not updating in table; only limited rows of data exist, but stream analytics is still sending new data to the database.

What would be the cause and from Grafana's side? I gave the 5s refresh for each panel. Is there any way to refresh the table for new data or continuously update the table?

In stream analytics the query is:

```sql
SELECT
      data1,
      data2,
      data3
INTO
     database_name
FROM
     Hub_name

SELECT *
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to send data from Azure IotHub using Stream analytics to a SQL database:

- **Create Event Hubs Namespace:**

  - In the Azure Portal, go to the Home page.
  - Search for "Event Hubs" and click on it.
  - Press the "Create" button.
  - Provide a name and location for the namespace, choose the Basic pricing tier, and click "Review + Create."
- **Save Connection String:**

  - After the namespace is created, go to the 'Shared access policies' tab.
  - Click on the RootManagerSharedAccessKey link.
  - Copy the 'Connection string- primary key' and save it for later use.
- **Create Event Hub:**

  - Go to the Overview tab of the Event Hubs namespace.
  - Click on the '+ Event Hub' button to create an Event Hub under the namespace.
  - Provide a name and set the partition count
  - Click "Create."
- Code taken from [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-central?pivots=programming-language-python) and[DOC2](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sending-streaming-data-from-azure-iot-central-to-azure-sql-database).

[image]

- **Configure Event Hubs as Data Export Destination:**

  - In the IoT Central Home Page, go to the Destination tab of Data Export.
  - Select Destination Type as Azure Event Hubs.
  - Provide the Connection String of Event Hubs saved earlier.
  - Select the name of the Event Hub created in the previous step.
  - Press the Save button.
- **Create Data Export:**

  - Go to the Exports tab of Data Export.
  - Provide a name for the export.
  - Select the type of data as Telemetry.
  - Choose the destination (Event Hub) created earlier.
  - Press the Save button.
- **Create Stream Analytics Job:**

  - In the Azure Portal, search for "Stream Analytics job" and click on it.
  - Provide a name for the new Stream Analytics job.
  - Select the number of streaming units .
  - Click "Create."

.  **Add Stream Input:**

- After the Stream Analytics job is created, go to the Overview page.
  -   Select the arrow link for Inputs.
  -   Choose Event Hub as the stream input type.
  -   Provide details for the Event Hub, including the namespace and Event Hub name.
  -   Click "Save."
- **Create Azure SQL Database:**

  - Go back to the Azure portal Home page.
  - Create a SQL database in the same region as the Stream Analytics job.
  - Provide the required details and click 'Review + create.'
  - Ensure that the logical server for Azure SQL database is in the same region as the Stream Analytics job.
- **Add Stream Output:**
- Go back to the Stream Analytics job.
- Go to the Outputs link.
- Select SQL Database as an output type.
- Provide details for the SQL database, including the table name.
- Click "Save."
- **Define SQL Table:**

  - Ensure that the SQL table (e.g., t1) is already created in the Azure SQL database.
  - **Edit Stream Analytics Query:**
  - Press on the Edit Query link in the Stream Analytics job.
  - Modify the SQL query to retrieve details from the telemetry data.
  - Test the query and save it.
  - . **Start Stream Analytics Job:**
  - Press the Start button in the Stream Analytics job.
    -.  **Monitor Stream Analytics Job:**
  - Check the Stream Analytics job Monitoring to understand how data streams are transferred from the input Event Hub to the output Azure SQL Database.
  - .  **Verify SQL Table:**
  - Check the SQL table to verify how streams of telemetry data are getting populated in the SQL Database.
    [image]

Comment: I have done all this, it is working fine. My only issue is the database is only reading certain limit of data and filling the table, later the new data are not stored in the table. Whenever I try to read table it is only showing the last fetched (3372 rows). Nothing new, meanwhile the stream analytics sending data to output as usual.